# How to repeat a single band in group header if the detail section spans for multiple pages?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to repeat the immediate band if the detail section spans for multiple pages.

Below is my source code related to group headers. Here I want to repeat the 2nd band (height = 25) if the detail band spanned to the next page. 
How can I repeat only the 2nd band

```
<group name="Lines">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ordernum}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="102">

        </band>
        <band height="25">

        </band>
    </groupHeader></group><detail>
    <band height="40" splitType="Stretch"></band></detail>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 1 group with 2 bands use 2 groups with 1 band and set the attribute [`isReprintHeaderOnEachPage`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRGroup.html#isReprintHeaderOnEachPage--) to true on the group you like to reprint on every page.

```
<group name="Lines1">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ordernum}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="102">
        ...
</group>
<group name="Lines2" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ordernum}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="25">
        ....
</group>
```

Comment: But I need to print only one band

Comment: @Shelly ok, I updated my answer, you just need two different groups.

Comment: So I need to move the other band to some other group. Now I have two bands inside same group

Comment: @Shelly Yes you need to make 2 different groups, since they behave differently.

Comment: Ohh Thank you, You saved my time. :)

Comment: Here I have a problem. How Can I put groupFooters inside these two differant 2 groups

Comment: @Shelly groupFooter is another thing, does groupFooter behave differently? or maybe you just need groupFooter in one group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191261/discussion-between-shelly-and-petter-friberg).