# How to count no of pages detail band spans over?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there any possibility that I count no of pages detail band spans over dynamically using a variable?

Comment: We need more details here, your question is unclear

Comment: This is attached with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513084/repeat-band-in-group-header-if-the-detail-section-spans-for-multiple-pages/55515160#55515160

Comment: @Shelly I can't see how that is directly related, I answered that also to clarify how you should solve that :), anyway I answered this since it was interesting to exclude title and summary band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of pages is a built in variable `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}`, a text field with `evaluationTime="Report"` will show the count of all the pages in report including both title band pages and summary band pages. If these pages (title/summary) are a fixed number you could just subtract this from `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}`

As example you have 1 page title band and no summary band, the number of pages that detail will use is:

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="973faf10-8714-48de-ac22-b746b5f56b1a"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}-1]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

However if these are not fixed, hence either title band or summary band will span dynamically over multiple pages a solution is to declare a variabile.

```
<variable name="detailBand_cnt" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Page" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Start at 0, increment (count) on each page with 1, this will work since variables are only evaluated while filling the detail band, it will not start before nor continue after the detail band.

**Full example**

*Run with a empty datasource of for example 10 records*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="CountDetailsPage" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isTitleNewPage="true" isSummaryNewPage="true" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="1070117d-1c41-40e8-85cd-d04958412665">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <variable name="detailBand_cnt" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Page" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="d5206823-c0fe-416a-aa9f-fdc6dc584f2b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Title page 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="38" width="100" height="1" uuid="465c7a1c-d59f-486d-8730-2e1a853f0b12"/>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="100" height="20" uuid="7c726918-e7d7-4a47-a5f4-a87561ef08fb"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Title page 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="20" uuid="ae3566d9-c2a2-41e5-99fa-cd184f1b1eee"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[On detail]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="20" uuid="38b0a124-e61b-46cb-8b4e-60e2f4ccd066"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Detail Page " + $V{detailBand_cnt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="70" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="c5f945f0-895d-4481-8895-6f945a070450"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{detailBand_cnt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="407" y="0" width="95" height="20" uuid="98da264d-689f-4382-99b2-f304e0202555"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Totale Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="502" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="973faf10-8714-48de-ac22-b746b5f56b1a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="ac518697-d616-47a9-a029-dfbb0d5f7ea3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Summary Page1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="1" uuid="6f92ae5a-2786-407f-b2bf-62c32287ae88"/>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="0e61769d-5bd0-4224-b905-425e90e0d87b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Summary Page 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="100" height="1" uuid="6f92ae5a-2786-407f-b2bf-62c32287ae88"/>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="100" height="20" uuid="0e61769d-5bd0-4224-b905-425e90e0d87b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Summary Page 3]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result (page 3 of 7)**

[image: result]

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much.

Comment: If I am going to use this variable to print header what would be the Print when expression

Comment: @Shelly You can use it as it is, it will start at 0, then increment on each page detail band is spanning until it hits summary band. But I'm not actually convinced you should use a variable like this to decided what should be printed in header. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Actually I have a header inside detail section and would like to print it only when detail section goes to the next page. So i thought of using this variable ? You think it wont work?

Comment: @Shelly *header inside detail section*... and print on page before if detail goes to next page, if not don't print it... that seems like a mess since the report is running, hence you can't know on page before what happens on page after. Maybe I did not understand correctly what you need or maybe you need to re-think your report.

Comment: Actually I have a frame inside detail section which I needed to print on top of every page if the detail section spans to multiple pages. As you are saying it is not possible ryt?